# Is there a way to copy the contents of a FILE* to a file descriptor?

Tags: c, file, file-descriptor

By this, I mean function-wise. I'm using fileno to convert a FILE* to a fd and it returns without any error, but when I use pread on that returned value from fileno, it gives me a bad file descriptor error. IE:

```
FILE* fin;
FILE* fout;
int fd, result;
fd = open("path", O_RDWR);
// Do stuff with fin and fout
// fout is the file with all of the stuff I want to copy to the fd
fd = fileno(fout);
result = pread(fd, buf, size, offset); // Bad file descriptor--returns a 9
```

I can't figure out what's causing pread to give me this error and it's driving me nuts.

Comment: Can't you open both ends with `open`?

Comment: Does `pread` *return* 9, or does it return -1 and set `errno` to 9?  If the former, that means there were 9 bytes left to read, by some coincidence.  If it returns -1 and `errno` is 9 (`EBADF`) then something already `fclose`d `fout`.

Comment: Don't you mean to be using `fout = fopen("path", "rw");`?  The code you posted shows `fout` is undefined, so it would horribly surprising if it did anything useful.

Comment: Sorry. pread returned -1 and set errno to 9. This is also just a snippet of my code--pasting the entire thing would've been really, really lengthy. As for fd, it's a file descriptor, so doesn't it have to use open instead of fopen? I haven't tried using "open" just yet, though.

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that `fout` is not a valid FILE* pointer. Have you verified it? Have you checked the return value of `fileno`?

Comment: No, that does not mean it's working fine. It means you invoked undefined behavior.

Comment: When I was reading the man page, I thought if it returns a number other than -1, that means that it worked okay?

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked the return from `fileno()`?  
[fileno() man page](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xsh/fileno.html)